# laravel 9 vite dont load functions in file

Tags: javascript, laravel, function, laravel-blade, vite

I want to load functions from Laravel Vite 9 and never load the functions always generate blank file.

For example in the `vite.config.js` I have:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
// import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'

export default defineConfig({

    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/css/dash.css',
            'resources/css/sailor.css',
            'resources/css/clientsailor.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
            'resources/js/sweetalert.js',
            'resources/js/bg-payment.js',
            'resources/js/oportunidades.js',
            'resources/js/sailor/sailor.js',
            'resources/js/dashboard/globaldash.js'
        ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

In my file globaldash.js

```
` function convertToLowerCase() {
    var input = document.getElementById('username');
    input.value = input.value.toLowerCase();
}`
```

In my blade template load the file :

```
@vite(['resources/js/dashboard/globaldash.js'])
```

And run command `npm run build`

But always I get blank content in file but if put code outside the functions the code appears fine. Does anyone know what's wrong?

I want the Laravel Vite load the functions well.

Comment: Vite uses mostly modules so you should do `export function convertToLowerCase` and import the function in the other files when you need it. If you do need to make it global for whatever reason add a `window.convertToLowerCase = convertToLowerCase` but also add a `export {}` to convert the file to a module

Comment: dont work. someone help me how i can the function work

Answer (score 1):

Skipping a function that is not directly called from your JavaScript file is a common behavior of build tools like Vite. To make Vite export the function you need, call it as `convertToLowerCase()`, or even better, export the function and import it into 'app.js' as shown in the example below:

Export:

```
export function convertToLowerCase() {
    var input = document.getElementById('username');
    input.value = input.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

Import into 'app.js' or any other file defined in the Laravel input plugin:

```
import { convertToLowerCase } from "./globaldash";

window.convertToLowerCase = convertToLowerCase;
```